# How can I pass an object, held within a vector, to an operator?

Tags: c++, class, vector, operator-overloading

My homework requires me to use a binary operator to manipulate complex numbers which are held in a class.

As each class is created (using new) in a loop reading from a file, in order to be able to refrence them I stored them within a vector (using pushback).

Current function definition:

```
Complex Complex::operator+ (vector<Complex> &v) 
{
result= new Complex;

result.real=real+v[y].real;
result.imaginary=imaginary+v[y].imaginary;

return result;
}
```

Current Definition within the Class:

```
Complex operator+ (vector<Complex> &v);
```

Called in main function by:
    result=v[x]+v[y];

Everything I have found online relies on the classes having a known name so you can send a pointer. I wanted to be able to choose which class to use at runtime so I can't give a set vector member.

I realise that this is all very wrong but I'm at a loss as to what the best way to do this would be.

Any help would be great! :)
Hx

Comment: There's absolutely no point in using `new` here.

Comment: Are you trying to add a Complex and another Complex, or a Complex with a vector of Complex? Your main function call suggests the former, your operator parameter the latter.

Answer (score 0):

```
result.real=real+v[y].real;
```

Where do you get `y` from?

You are defining addition of a `Complex` with a `std::vector<Complex>`. This is a bit strange . Usually you would want to define a `Complex` + `Complex` overload and use that (*ONLY as a syntactic convenience when it is obvious or mathematically defined and unambiguous*) on variables of that type (e.g. that you might index/access out of your array/vector). The behaviour you are currently defining shouldn't be in an operator overload, but just a plain function.

Your usage of `new` is unnecessary and is causing a memory leak because there is no corresponding `delete`, and hence that memory address in the heap is not getting released. You should just initialise it as a regular stack variable:

```
Complex result;
```

Prefer stack allocation to heap allocation whenever you can; not only does it avoid memory problems, but it is also faster.

Either way this variable is a temporary that has two copies made; one on the return, and another inside the vector on `push_back`.

In terms of your question, I think what you want is that you have some aggregating class that operates on different numeric types and making use of operator overloading.

You can use templates to define the aggregation class as a templated class, and then instantiate it with you numeric types e.g. `Complex`  (just make sure they have an `operator+()` defined), then in some function in the class you can make use of the `+` overload on the templated variables:

```
template <typename T>
class MyNumericAggregatorClass
//... in some function
// T a; T b;
T result = a + b;
//...
```

The alternative to this is to use  polymorphism to create a base numeric class with a `virtual operator+()`, and subclasses  (e.g. `Complex`) that override this operator, then you can operate on a collection of base class pointers.

To give any further guidance, more of your code should be shown. But if all you are trying to do is sum instances of a numeric type stored in a vector using operator+, then check out `std::accumulate` from the STL and your problem is solved.